# Javascript filter by html tags (h2 and span)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to search items by the **Title** and **City**.

```
$(list).find("li > div > h3:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
```

Here is the [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sc9ys/6/).

I do understand that `li > div` means that `div` is inside `li`, am I right?

Not working at all, probably because it doesn't detect H3..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out [in the documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

> **Child Selector (“parent > child”)** Description: Selects all **direct child** elements specified by "child" of elements specified by >
>   "parent".

You are not looking for direct childs.

I would do:

```
$(list).find("li div h3:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
```

Comment: So I am correct. But it's possible to do something like `li > div > li > h3` ?

Comment: @user3243925 why do you want do to that if it doesn't work in this case? You should use the option I offered or use `find`.

Comment: Well, kind of works. But when I type something like 'Google' it should hide the other divs. I know that for this I would have to use the `function hide` probably? Plus, if I clear the input I would like to see all again and it's not working.

Comment: @user3243925 well that's another question my friend. I solved the problem with your selector, now you should open another question for your new problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll mark this as correct answer and then open a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(list).find("li  div  h3:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
                $(list).find("li  div  h3:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
```

use this